# Заголовки причин закрытия вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, причины-закрытия

При голосовании за закрытие вопроса присутствуют в частности следующие пункты:

[image: необходимо ...]

Каждый раз читая эти заголовки мне приходится читать и более мелкий текст, чтобы выбрать причину более правильно (хотя и в этом случае не всегда можно однозначно верно выбрать тот или иной пункт, т.к. например, в текущей формулировке вопрос может подпадать сразу под несколько). Может быть, конечно, я один такой уникальный и всем остальным заголовок, написанный полужирным шрифтом, уже позволяет сделать правильный выбор. Тем не менее, мне кажется, что вот этот полужирный текст нуждается в исправлении, дабы при выборе причины реже обращаться к тексту пояснения этих пунктов.

Comment: Последний пункт в причинах закрытия, кстати, вообще не про количество возможных правильных ответов. А первый - не про "неясность". Он про "неполность" :(

Comment: @PashaPash, получается надо не только заголовки, но описание менять.

Comment: Раньше там было написано "однозначно" вместо "объективно", и вы не представляете сколько сил пришлось потратить на смену одного слова :) На самом деле краткая формулировка "Вопрос <плох тем-то>" или даже "плох тем-то" гораздо ближе к подходу, принятому на enSO. "Слишком общий" или "Зависит от мнения" лично мне больше нравится, чем текущий вариант. Но еще раз проходить квест со уговариванием *сами знаете кого* я не хочу :(

Comment: Общий подход к смене текстовок - завести отдельный пост на смену конкретной текстовки, описать проблему, предложить вариант, уговорить всех подряд за него проголосовать. Потом уговорить Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ поменять текстовку.

Comment: Для себя решил проблему проще - читаю эти строки в английском варианте (**unclear what you asking, too broad, primarily opinion-based**) и сразу всё становится легко и понятно ;-) *а еще плюс в том, что нет повторений слова "вопрос" каждый раз.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вынесете предложения в ответ, чтобы другие участники могли проголосовать за различные варианты.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky сделано.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а дальше-то что?

Comment: @andreycha возможно дальше стоит все эти пункты рассматривать по отдельности (т.е. голосовать за каждую причину с описанием отдельно). А то [подобные темы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3573/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc) только будут плодиться, и выбрать какой-то единственный вариант будет сложнее. Может быть для начала эти темы стоит объединить.

Comment: @andreycha Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на публикацию «[Зачем на сайте присутствует функционал закрытия вопросов?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1936/)», в частности, на требования к предложениям внесения изменений (в конце). На мой взгляд, без этих требований, зачастую, предложения внесения изменений звучат как «я считаю вари N более понятным». То есть суждения субъективны, а нам надо постараться быть как можно более объективными.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю следующие варианты заголовков и небольшое уточнение в скобках:

- **вопрос не ясен** (нельзя дать ответ)
- **вопрос слишком общий** (ответ будет очень длинный)
- **вопрос может быть понят двояко** (правильных ответов может быть несколько)

Comment: 1 и 3-я текстовки не соответствуют ни причинам закрытия на ruSO, ни причинам закрытия на enSO.

Comment: @PashaPash наверное было бы неплохо озвучить альтернативы, ну или исправить мой ответ.

Comment: 3-й просто не соответствует самой причине закрытия, суть которой "ответ на вопрос будет *полностью* зависеть от *мнения* отвечающего". Это причина для закрытия вопросов "что лучше - windows или linux?". Т.е. вопрос *однозначен*, но ответ на него скорее всего будет *необъективен*. Ваша же текстовка предполагает закрытие вопроса только за то, что на него дано два ответа (что вообще-то норма для SO). Исправлять ваш ответ не буду - за него люди уже проголосовали. Свой постить - тоже, т.к. не могу придумать короткую текстовку для первого пункта :(

Comment: @PashaPash для первого пункта - "вопрос не полон", по Вашему же первому комментарию к теме.

Comment: мне не нравится этот вариант, иначе я бы его давно предложил :)